# VueJS Bootstrap CSS how to place element bottom of the page?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

[image]

I want to bring my footer (Copyrights statement) down in the page. But It adds some additional white space below the footer. How come I remove this **additional white space**?

I'm doing in this VueJS project. This is my codes.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="fluid-container">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div style="min-height:610px;">

      <router-view></router-view>

    </div>

<div>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>

  </div>
</template>
```

**footer.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="fluid-container">
    <p class="text-center">Copyright &copy 2018, ABC Marketing. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script></script>
<style scoped>
div{
  color: white;
  background-color: #003459;

}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you create code snip please?

Comment: What do you mean by code snip? This is all my code for this.

Comment: You didn't include your js code here.  Yours is not a single file project.
Maybe you can set up a jsfiddle so that others can try to help easier.

Comment: You missed the semicolon after ``&copy``.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that in footer.vue you wrapped copyright text in p tag, as per bootstrap 4 **p tag has margin-bottom: 1rem;** if you removed the margin-bottom it will fixed at bottom of the page.

```css
.fluid-container.footer{
  background: blue;
}
.fluid-container.footer > *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="min-height:610px;">
</div>

<div>
  <div class="fluid-container footer">
    <p class="text-center">Copyright &copy; 2018, ABC Marketing. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You missed the semicolon after ``&copy``.

Comment: I had to add <div>&nbsp;</div> after the <p> so that it was all the way till page end.

Comment: thx it works very well whit this classes **fluid-container** and **footer**!